# Why does this innocent function cause a segfault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sfml

I'm trying to code metaballs in C++/SFML, my program works just fine in a single thread. I tried to write an MRE to find the problem and here's what I got:

main.cpp

```
// main

#include <iostream>
#include "threader.h"

float func(float x, float y, float a, float b, float r) {
    return 1.f / sqrt((x - a)*(x - a) + (y - b)*(x - b));
}

int main () {

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(2800, 1800), "");
    window.setFramerateLimit(20);
    sf::Event event{};
    threader tf(window);
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
            case sf::Event::Closed: {
                window.close();
            }
            }
        }
        window.clear();

        tf.parallel(func);

        window.display();
    }
}
```

threader.h

```
//threader_H

#pragma once

#include <array>
#include <thread>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class threader {
public:
    int threadCount = 4;
    std::array<std::thread, 4> threads;
    sf::RenderWindow& window;
public:
    explicit threader(sf::RenderWindow& w) : window(w) {};

    void strip(int start, int end, const std::function<float(float, float, float, float, float)>& func);
    void parallel(const std::function<float(float, float, float, float, float)>& func);

};
```

threader.cpp

```
// threader_CPP

#include "threader.h"
#include <iostream>


void threader::strip (int start, int end, const std::function<float (float, float, float, float, float)> &func) {
    for (int X = start; X < end; X += 10) {
        for (int Y = 0; Y < window.getSize().y; Y += 10) {
            auto x = static_cast<float>(X);
            auto y = static_cast<float>(Y);

            x = x / 2800.f * 4 + 0 - 4 / 2.f;
            y = -((1800.f - y) / 1800 * 4 + 0 - 4 / 2.f);

            if (func(x, y, 1, 2, 3) > 1) {
                sf::CircleShape circle(20);
                circle.setPointCount(3);
                circle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);
                circle.setPosition(X, Y);
                window.draw(circle);
            }
        }
    }
}

void threader::parallel (const std::function<float (float, float, float, float, float)> &func) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = window.getSize().x / threadCount;
    for (auto& t : threads) {
        t = std::thread(&threader::strip, this, start, end, func);
        start = end;
        end += window.getSize().x / threadCount;
    }
    for (auto& t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }

}
```

Now for the explanation. `threader` is a class which has two methods: `strip` that calculates a function for a given strip of the `window` and `parallel` that creates threads to separately calculate my function for every strip. This code doesn't work:

[image: A successful result of any C++ program is a segfault :)]

But here's the catch: if I adjust the function `void func(...)` in main to return `1.f / sqrt((x - a) + (y - b))`, everything works just fine. What is happening? How a simple calculation can cause a segfault? help please...

EDIT 1: Written in CLion, C++ 20.

EDIT 2: If anything here makes sense, please explain it to me.
[image: debugger]

Comment: There are no "innocent functions" in c++.

Comment: @JasonLiam by innocent I mean it doesn't have any ```[]``` or ```new``` or anything like that

Comment: Why don't you launch the code under a debugger? It will break on that segfault, allowing you to see the reason why.

Comment: I don't know anything about sfml, but I'm immediately suspicious of drawing to a window in multiple threads

Comment: @Caleth as far as I know, window is just an array with pixel values as every element

Comment: Note that an [`sf:: RenderWindow`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1RenderWindow.php) is far more than just a pixel array.  In particular, the docs. state `"A window is active only on the current thread, if you want to make it active on another thread you have to deactivate it on the previous thread first if it was active..."`.

Comment: @G.M. that's all great (thank you for letting me know), but still if I edit the function to return a different value, everything works just fine. Why could that be? oh.. maybe it so happens that my ```if``` statement makes the program avoid other threads, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to undefined behaviour, where breakage isn't guaranteed

Comment: As an aside, I would use one of the `std` algorithms with a [parallel execution policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), rather than launch a bunch of threads, to carve up parallel work

Comment: @Caleth Could you please write a simple example similar to my code using what you mentioned? I don't quite get what is happening there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to draw to the window on multiple threads, I would instead use `std` algorithms to filter the points to draw circles, and draw them all on the main thread.

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> getPoints(const sf::RenderWindow& window) {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> points;
    for (int X = 0; X < window.getSize().x; X += 10) {
        for (int Y = 0; Y < window.getSize().y; Y += 10) {
            points.emplace_back(X, Y);
        }
    }
    return points;
}

template<typename F>
auto filter(F f) {
    return [f](const std::pair<int, int> & point) {
        auto x = static_cast<float>(point.first);
        auto y = static_cast<float>(point.second);

        x = x / 2800.f * 4 + 0 - 4 / 2.f;
        y = -((1800.f - y) / 1800 * 4 + 0 - 4 / 2.f);

        return (func(x, y, 1, 2, 3) > 1);
    }
}

sf::CircleShape toCircle(int X, int Y) {
    sf::CircleShape circle(20);
    circle.setPointCount(3);
    circle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);
    circle.setPosition(X, Y);
    return circle;
}

template <typename F>
void drawCircles(sf::RenderWindow& window, F f) {
    auto points = getPoints(window);
    auto end = std::remove_if(std::execution::par, points.begin(), points.end(), filter(f));
    points.erase(end, points.end());
    for (auto & [X, Y] : points) {
        window.draw(toCircle(X, Y));
    }
}

float func(float x, float y, float a, float b, float r) {
    return 1.f / sqrt((x - a)*(x - a) + (y - b)*(x - b));
}

int main () {

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(2800, 1800), "");
    window.setFramerateLimit(20);
    sf::Event event{};
    threader tf(window);
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
            case sf::Event::Closed: {
                window.close();
            }
            }
        }
        window.clear();

        drawCircles(window, func);

        window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason std::execution::par is not working, I included everything(

Comment: @Betydlig it's a C++17 library feature, which might not be available by default in your compiler

Comment: I'm not totally sure if that's enough but I'm using CLion with this option:
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

Comment: Oh, it's just [not implemented by clang yet](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/17#C.2B.2B17_library_features) :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with trying to render from multiple threads without properly switching GL contexts.
Since you are doing this on the CPU, here are some options:

1. Make multiple sf::RenderTexture objects, render to each one of them in a separate thread (don't forget to call display() at the end), then draw them on the main thread in some sprites. (harder and not sure it is the way to go, but I don't know what you want to do in the end)
2. Make multiple sf::Image objects, render to each one of them in a separate thread, then draw them on the main thread in some sprites.
3. Make just one sf::Image object, each thread renders in a separate area of the image, then draw the image on the main thread in some sprite.

options 2 & 3 make it more easy to work with at a pixel level, also faster. Make sure you traverse the image in a cache friendly way (line by line most likely)

I would go with 2 or 3 depending on how you think it's better for your application.

Also, use sf::Transform for the transformation from screen space (Image space) to world space where the metaballs live.

https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Image.php

https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Transform.php#ab42a0bb7a252c6d221004f6372ce5fdc

Comment: thank you, I’ll try that and come back